# trying to get a phone number without any space

Tags: c#

Im trying to create a program to ask the user to enter a phone number without any spaces and hyphen using loop. if the user enter any space or any hyphen the  program should crush and ask the user to try again . But i really having hard time with the loop. i tired few times it did not work so far what i have is that ask the user a to enter a number and read the number .If you could me help i really  appreciate your help.

```
int num;

Console.WriteLine("plz enter your phone  number ");
num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("the phone number :" + num);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: A phone number is not an integer, representing one as such can overflow and will lose any leading zeros.  Read it as a string, replace spaces and hyphens, check its numeric then validate its a reasonable length.

Comment: `string pno = "123 456 789";
var s = pno.Replace(" ","");`

Comment: use a MaskedTextBox with the proper mask

Comment: Are you asking how to filter spaces and hyphens from the phone number or how to ask the user to reenter a value if what they entered is invalid?

Comment: You want to keep looping until a valid number is entered.

    bool bValidPhoneNumber = false;
    string strPhoneNumber = string.empty;
    
    while (bValidPhoneNumber == false)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid phone number: ");
         strPhoneNumber = Console.ReadLine().Replace(" ","").Replace("-","");
         if (strPhoneNumber.All(char.IsDigit) != false)
              bValidPhoneNumber = true;
    }

Answer (score 4):

You can try using *Linq* to filter out just digits:

```
 string source = "+039 (923) 1234-456-78";

 // 039923123445678
 string result = string.Concat(source.Where(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9'));
```

Please, notice that some phone numbers can be *quite long* (country code, area code etc.) and thus don't fit `int`; another problem is that a number can well start with *zero* (e.g. `+039` is a country code for Italy when `39` can be treated as area code for Monza) which should be *preserved*.

Comment: Why not using `char.IsDigit` ?

Comment: @Fabjan: `char.IsDigit` will pass all *unicode* digits (including, say, *persian* ones)

Comment: char.IsDigit('๑') == true

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Well that's a good point.

Comment: Not only should you keep the 0, but also the '+' which denotes the international calling code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int num;
string input;

Console.WriteLine("plz enter your phone  number ");
input = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("the phone number: {0}", input.replace(" ", "").Replace("-",""));
```

and now if you want to use that num somewhere as an integer, use it from num:

```
num = Convert.ToInt32(input);
```

Comment: but for num,replace it gives me an errors

Comment: I was hoping you would use a string input after the comments and answers.

Comment: Edited the solution

Comment: It still shows "num.replace" - it should be "input.Replace".

Comment: i really like your solutions but what if the user enter a space ??? the program has to crush this is the part where i have difficulty

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not using a Winforms control, you really have very little control of user input and can't assume anything.  As such, you really need to read the user input as a string.

```
Console.WriteLine("plz enter your phone  number ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
```

From there, my recommendation would be to strip out all non-digits:

```
input = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, @"\D", string.Empty);
```

And then you can attempt to render this as a number:

```
long phoneNumber;
Int64.TryParse(input, out phoneNumber);
```

Note: I think integers are too small for what you need -- use a big int.

Comment: not only `int` too small (in general) case, but some numbers *must* start with `0`, e.g. `039 123456789` - *Italy* (country code `039`) when changed to `39 123456789` can well be cofused with area code for *Monza* in Italy